# How to add a parameter to a case statement to determine the field to pull data from in SQL Server

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL query in SSRS that I want to use a case when statement to determine what column to pull data on. My data has two types of ID: a `headquarter id` and a `bt id`. Based upon the selection the user chooses I want to use either the `bt.ID` or the `H.hq`_id to pull the data from. See below:

```
CASE WHEN @IDTYPE = 'BT' THEN BT.ID ELSE H.HQ_ID END
```

`@IDTYPE` can be either `BT` or `HQ`. I am hoping that I can do this to limit my query right off.

When I try my query I get the following error:

> The parameter is incorrect

What am I doing wrong or can I even do this?

Comment: Can you share your complete query, that will really help to identify the issue

Comment: You can definitely do this. Your query looks fine. Make sure you use Query Designer (in the dataset properties screen) and press the red exclamation mark to test. A dialog should appear asking you to enter a parameter. Next to it is a dropdown box. Set that to "Text" and hit OK. As long as it runs fine, hit OK in the query designer, it will ask for the parameter again do the same thing. Hit OK again and your query is done. If you still have issues, make sure you have made a parameter with the matching name in the parameter folder. Make sure your default (if you have one) is a valid value.